# XCode, Storyboard, View Controller items are not being displayed

Tags: xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

When opening up a project today, there is some weird behavior in XCode. Things have disappeared in the `storyboard` view like the `NavigationBar` in `viewController`, the buttons associated with it, etc. I can see in the Scene list that they still exist. Is there any way to have these show up again?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add a navigation controller to your storyboard and make your view controller the root. You cannot simply set the top bar in simulated metrics in storyboard to navigation bar.